# Issue with APOSE.CELLS in Java

Tags: java, excel, sorting, aspose-cells

I am using ASPOSE.CELLS to sort an excel sheet but I am getting an exception when I am trying to save a workbook. What can the problem be? The code is also generating a corrupted excel workbook.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.font.FontManager.getFontPath(Z)Ljava/lang/String;
at com.aspose.cells.a.c.cf.p(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.a.c.cf.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.b.a.b.g.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.b.a.b.g.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.ou.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.ou.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.ou.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Worksheet.autoFitRow(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.jH.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.WorksheetCollection.r(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.WorksheetCollection.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.WorksheetCollection.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.WorksheetCollection.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.WorksheetCollection.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.save(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.save(Unknown Source)
at AsposeDataSort.main(AsposeDataSort.java:67)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the ASpose.cells Maven plugin for Eclipse IDE and it is now working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The exception may be caused by a bug in Aspose.Cells or the file you are loading may have some internal problems which are causing this exception. Please post your issue in Aspose.Cells forum. Also provide us your sample code and source excel file(s) you are using inside your code.

Here is a link to Aspose.Cells forum

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I am trying to get the artifact from maven. But the report doesn't exist. Is this project discontinued? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you want to download the most recent version of Aspose.Cells for Java. It is at the moment 17.11.2. You can download it from this link. ---
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/sk1dnqt69ic9spl/aspose-cells-17.11.2-java.zip?dl=0 --- Regards, Shakeel

Comment: I was trying to use the maven entry. It was not working. Anyhow, is there a way to capture an image of a worksheet with conditional formatting? I couldn't find any documentation for that :(

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Worksheet 2 Image is very well-supported and well-documented by Aspose.Cells. Please search the keywords on google like - Export Range of Cells in a Worksheet to Image - Render the Worksheet and Workbook to Image using ImageOrPrintOptions - Converting Worksheet to Image using ImageOrPrint Options - You will find plenty of code for it. Please note, when you render worksheet to image, it also renders Conditional Formatting. Regards.